# How do I add an event listener on a Class constructer with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, ecmascript-6

I need the dice's this.value to change when I click on the dice, but right now I'm just trying to get it to display an alert but I can't even do that. I have looked deep into e.target and just about everything I can find, but I just don't know what I'm missing I feel like this is a silly question, but I've spent over an hour now trying to figure this out and I can't get it.

```js
function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
const diceArray = [];
const body = document.body;

class Die {
  constructor() {
    this.value = this.roll();
    this.div = $(`<div class="a-die d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><h1 class="die-text">${this.value}</h1></div>`);
    diceArray.push(this);
    $('#diceHolder').append(this.div);
    this.div.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert('hello');
    })
  }
  roll = () => {
    return randomNumber(1, 7);
  }
  refreshView = () => {
    $(this.div).find('h1').text(this.value);
  }
  rollAll = () => {
    $(this.value).replaceWith(randomNumber(1, 7));
  }
}



$('#genDice').on('click', () => {
  let thisDie = new Die()
});
$('#yahtzee').on('click', () => $('.die-text').text(randomNumber(1, 7)));
$('#sumDice').on('click', () => {
  const thing = diceArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
    return acc + val.value;
  }, 0)
  alert(thing);
})

$('#rollDice').on('click', () => diceArray.forEach(val => {
  // console.log(val);
  val.value = randomNumber(1, 7);
  val.refreshView();
}));
$('#remove').on('click', () => {
  $('.a-die').remove()
  $(diceArray).empty();
});
console.log(diceArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around mb-5 mt-2 py-3 bg-light" style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <div id="genDice" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Die</div>
  <div id="rollDice" class="btn btn-secondary">Roll All Die</div>
  <div id="sumDice" class="btn btn-success">Sum All Dice</div>
  <div id="yahtzee" class="btn btn-danger">Yahtzee</div>
  <div id="remove" class="btn btn-dark">Bye-Bye</div>
</div>
<div id="diceHolder" class="d-flex justify-content-evenly"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were multiple problems here:

1. `this.div` is a jQuery object that you can't use `.addEventListener()` on to register for the click event.  Much better to just use jQuery's `.click()` method on the jQuery object.
2. `refreshView()` was trying to make a jQuery object of a jQuery object.  While apparently that can work, it's redundant and shouldn't be done that way.
3. Your method definition using arrow functions was using a newish syntax (field declarations) that does not define full-fledged methods on the prototype - it works differently.  While it can be made to work in this specific case, I would not recommended it because it's not as extensible as regular methods (and not on the prototype) and thus has limitations with subclassing.  So, methods should generally be defined as normal functions, not assigned as arrow functions.  There are some special use cases where you want all your methods to be "bound" methods that you may want to use field definitions like you were using, but I would only recommend using that syntax if you specifically know why you're doing it and you're leveraging that for a specific reason.
4. `rollAll()` probably does not work as shown because `$(this.value)` will be doing `$(someNumber)` which is unlikely to match anything.  You need to pass a Dom Element, a jQuery object or a CSS selector t0 `$(x)`.

So, here's the code with those changes in it:

```
class Die {
    constructor() {
        this.value = this.roll();
        this.div = $(`<div class="a-die d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><h1 class="die-text">${this.value}</h1></div>`);
        diceArray.push(this);
        $('#diceHolder').append(this.div);
        this.div.click(() => {
            alert('hello');
        });
    }
    roll() {
        return randomNumber(1, 7);
    }
    refreshView() {
        this.div.find('h1').text(this.value);
    }
    rollAll() {
        $(this.value).replaceWith(randomNumber(1, 7));
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
let die = new Die();
die.refreshView();
```

And, you need to make sure that this code does not run before the page DOM is loaded into the page so that your jQuery references will work properly against the already loaded DOM.

---

There's a third problem with the `rollAll()` method.  You're trying to do `$(this.value)`, but `this.value` is a random number which is unlikely  to work properly in `$()` to actually find an element in your DOM.  You need to pass a selector or an HTML element to `$()` in order to use it.

Comment: @Phil - OK, I modified the code to move the `addEventListener()` to `this.div` which is a guess for what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Phil - I'm answering based on the code shown in which there's no mention of Babel at all and arrow functions are completely out of place.  In fact, the question is tagged ES6.  If the OP wants to add some Babel-ness to the question, then we'll deal with it then.

Comment: Fair call. I was just pointing out a possibility since I thought exactly the same thing as in your first paragraph. OP's syntax doesn't even look valid to me so I was wondering how it worked at all

Comment: I changed the event listener to a regular function and changed it to this.div.addEventListener and it still doesn't alert

Comment: @Wayne - Please show a complete, [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code (something we can run, including the relevant HTML).  Also, please report exactly what errors are shown in the browser console.

Comment: @Wayne - I made a couple other corrections.  You are really mixing up jQuery objects with regular HTML objects and very much confusing things.  I would not write the code this way at all.  Please take ALL the code since I made about 5-10 different changes to fix a number of things.

Comment: @Phil - Yeah, `this.div` is already a  jQuery object so I just changed to `this.div.click()`.  This code was a peeling onion of successive problems.

Comment: I just started learning how to code a few months ago I apologize if it's that bad. I was taught to use arrow functions in the constructor since it auto binds this. I updated the code hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I just checked the arrow function method thing and apparently it _does_ work. TIL ~ https://jsfiddle.net/uheto1q8/

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you it worked with .click()! Why did it not work with addEventListener, but did with click()?

Comment: @Wayne - Because `this.div` is a jQuery object that does not have a `.addEventListener()` method that works with click.  That method is on the DOM object itself, not on the jQuery object.  You were mixing up jQuery objects with DOM objects and the two are not interchangeable.

Comment: I see, thank you again! So @Phil am I able to use arrow functions or is it still a bad idea?

Comment: @Wayne - Apparently the arrow function construct you were using does work in some circumstances.  But, I would not recommend using it.  It's just complicated.  Methods should be normal functions so that they inherit the `this` value from the object they are called on.  Besides, the syntax I show is simpler to write and understand.

Comment: @Phil - I've cleaned up my answer to explain a bit about the arrow functions which are field declarations and are automatically bound to the object and don't go directly on the prototype.